# Zoomed images all the same in Elevate Zoom plugin

Tags: jquery, css

I can't get the right image to show in the zoom window for the elevate zoom plugin.
I'm using jcarousel scroll for my thumbnails. That is why my thumbnails are in a different div.
The page works great. I click on a thumbnail in the scroll box and it displays an image to the right. I then hover over that displayed image to zoom it. When I hover on the different images displayed to the right I get the same image in the zoom window.
When I hover on the image of the horse I get the image of the horse in the zoom window.

When I hover on the image of the bird I get the image of the horse in the zoom window.

When I hover on the image of the tree I get the image of the horse in the zoom window.

When I hover on the image of the chair I get the image of the horse in the zoom window.

I get the same image in the zoom window for all the different images displayed. I'm thinking it is the js and ID's that need work on.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div id="slideshow-main">
    <ul>
        <li class="p1 active">
            <a href="#">
                <img id="zoom_mw" src="images/horsesmall.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/horsebig.jpg" alt=""/><br />
                <span class="content"><h1>Horse</h1><p>Text, Text, Text.</p></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="p2">
            <a href="#">
                <img id="zoom_mw" src="images/birdsmall.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/birdbig.jpg" alt=""/><br />
                <span class="content"><h1>Bird</h1><p>Text, Text, Text.</p></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="p3">
            <a href="#">
                <img id="zoom_mw" src="images/treesmall.jpg" data-zoom-   image="images/treebig.jpg" alt=""/><br />
                <span class="content"><h1>Tree</h1><p>Text, Text, Text.</p></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="p4">
            <a href="#">
                <img id="zoom_mw" src="images/chairsmall.jpg" data-zoom-image="images/chairbig.jpg" alt=""/><br />
                <span class="content"><h1>Chair</h1><p>Text, Text, Text.</p></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>                                       
</div>


<div id="slideshow-carousel" style="margin-top: -289px; position: absolute;">               
      <ul id="carousel" class="jcarousel jcarousel-skin-tango">
        <li><a href="#" rel="p1"><img src="images/horsethumb.jpg" width="110" height="110" alt="#"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="p2"><img src="images/birdthumb.jpg" width="110" height="110" alt="#"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="p3"><img src="images/treethumb.jpg" width="110" height="110" alt="#"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="p4"><img src="images/chairthumb.jpg" width="110" height="110" alt="#"/></a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#zoom_mw").elevateZoom({gallery:'slideshow-main', scrollZoom : true', 
 galleryActiveClass:'active'}); 
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find gallery example [here](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples) in **External Controls** section. 
That code show you how to remove **galleryActiveClass** and add it again. My answer maybe too late, but someone can find it useful.